# Set value to variable and modify based on condition SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query where I need to declare a variable and set value to it. Then in the select statement based on one of the column values (`max_val`) I would need to change the value of the variable if variable value exceeds the value in `max_col`. The basic query looks like the one below:

```
Declare @variable int
Set @variable = x

select * from (
  select 
    *, 
    row_number () over (partition by account_id, product order by revenue desc) as rk 
  from (
    select * 
    from dataset
    where account_id = 'abc'
    and product = 'xyz'
    and @variable between min_val and max_val
  ) x 
) y
where y.rk =1;
```

In this query if `@variable > max_val`, then no records will be shown. However, I want to include a condition such that when the above criteria matches, `@variable` is assigned value of `max_val`.

Comment: In SQL Server, you cannot both return rows and set a variable in a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce this after the second line, to put the right value into `@variable`:

```
select @variable = case
                        when max(max_val) > @variable then @variable
                        else max(max_val)
                    end
from dataset
where account_id = 'abc'
and product = 'xyz'
```

Comment: Not sure if I'm doing something wrong but the query is still giving me no records. If I remove the condition "and @variable between min_val and max_val" I'm getting a record. Ideally with the new condition applied, I should get the same record
Thanks for your quick response though!!

Comment: @Abhi Can you inspect the value of `@variable` before the query executes? Is it what you would expect?

Comment: @Wolf Sorry, the query is working but only for few of the values in the product column. I think I will need to check attributes of other columns once and get back to you. Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: Typo? Should your case clause not be `case when max(max_val)<@variable then @variable else max(max_val) end`?

Comment: @cars10 I don't think so: `@variable` should end up being `between min_val and max_val`. This means that if it's less than the max `max_val`, it should probably keep its value.

Comment: @Abhi perhaps you should perform the same check with the lower bound.

Comment: @w0lf I have about 5 different products with different min_val and max_val for each product. However, the variable entered will be the same and the same condition holds in case of each product. How can I modify the query now to get results of all 5 products in one query? 
Please let me know if this is too confusing.. I will trying framing it differently or with an example

Comment: I know the long way would be to declare a different variable for each product and have the query but was wondering if I could loop it any way to have a smaller query